# How to extract the file with same name from different directories in linux?

Tags: linux, file, extract

I have lots of folders with the same file name, like:

```
   fd1/01.wh.txt  
   ff2/01.wh.txt  
   fk2/01.wh.txt 
   fd3/01.wh.txt
```

I want to extract *01.wh.txt* from these different directories, and get a new folder including all *01.wh.txt* with the specific parent code:

```
new_folder/   
   fd1.01.wh.txt 
   ff2.01.wh.txt  
   fk2.01.wh.txt  
   fd3.01.wh.txt
```

How to execute the code in the Linux system?

Comment: Use find command

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I input the code `find -name '01.wh.txt' -type f > temr`  `cp temr testresult/`, but I just got the temr file in the testresult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

for i in `find . -name "*.txt"`; do echo $i; fname=`echo $i|sed 's/\//-/g'`; echo $fname; cp $i ./newdir/$fname; done